# Why is Kotlin not printing anything?

Tags: kotlin

I'm pretty new at Kotlin and I have this issue:

I created some objects, and I'm trying to call the funcion code, but when I do it in my main class, it doesn't prints anything, like this:

```
var cabesa = Programmer("cabesota", 10, arrayOf(Programmer.Language.JAVASCRIPT))
cabesa.code()
```

That doesnt print anything, but if I add any other print after the code() call, it prints correctly, why is this happening?

This is the class programmer:

```
class Programmer (var name: String,var age: Int,var languages: Array<Language>) {

    enum class Language{
        KOTLIN,
        SWIFT,
        JAVASCRIPT,
        JAVA
    }

    fun code(){
        for(i in languages){
            print("$name programa en: ")
            print("$i ")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce it and it seems to be working. https://pl.kotl.in/I-sfRI4bu

Comment: Please make sure you're calling the code from the `main()` method.